# Customize DataGrid Group Name

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using the Silverlight Toolkit DataGrid.  Grouping is working fine, thanks to the `PagedCollectionView` class.

My question is, is there an easy way to customize the text of the group header?  When I group by `"CurrentBook.SubTitle"` (just testing it out - grouping by a book's subtitle doesn't actually make sense) it displays "CurrentBook.SubTitle" in the group header of the grid, when I'd prefer just SubTitle.

Obviously I could just make a new property in my ViewModel called SubTitle that passes along CurrentBook.SubTitle, but I'm just wondering if there is any built-in way to affect the group header text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little difficult to answer this without seeing an example of your code. Follow the advice [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrowgroupheader%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and make a style for the `DataGridRowGroupHeader` with something like `PropertyName="{Binding Collection Path=Name}"` and add that style to the `RowGroupHeaderStyles` Property. Im not sure how much more specific I can get without seeing more though.